# Crystal report sql expression field

Tags: asp.net, sql, crystal-reports

I'm using asp.net crystal report and this is a sql query I'm using:

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CASE 
                WHEN 
            CASE WHEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT > 0 THEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END = 0 THEN NULL 
                ELSE 
            CASE WHEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT > 0 THEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END 
            END) Q3_DR,
             CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), CASE 
                WHEN (- 1 * 
            CASE WHEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT < 0 THEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN NULL 
                ELSE - 1 * 
            CASE WHEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT < 0 THEN GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END 
            END) Q3_CR,
```

I want to write this query into crystal report sql expression field.

How can I convert this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two expressions listed, SQL expression code for each is

q3_dr :

> **case when** GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT > 0 **then** GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT **end**

q3_cr :

> **case when** GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT < 0 **then** -GLDD_DOC_AMOUNT **end**